# Equivalent of GroupBy and Having clause in Relational Algebra

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, relational-algebra

I was doing an assignment where I had to convert SQL queries into Relational Algebra queries. I got stuck in converting the `group by` clause.

Could anyone please tell me how the group by clause can be written in relational algebra?

e.g.:

```
SELECT job, sal 
  FROM emp
 GROUP BY job
       ;
```

Thanks!

Comment: That is not valid SQL. `sal` would need to be included in the `GROUP BY` or aggregated.

Comment: Which would just effectively give you the same as leaving the `group by` out...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604969/converting-aggregate-operators-from-sql-to-relational-algebra/7622518#7622518

Comment: @Ben: not the same: `SELECT job, sal FROM emp GROUP BY job, sal;` is equivalent to `SELECT DISTINCT job, sal FROM emp;` i.e. note the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your query is wrong you cannot select something that you did not group unless you use aggregation. I assume you want to get sum of the sal.

job F sum(sal), job(emp).

Comment: yea sry about tht. i DID want to get the sum of salary

Answer (score 3):

Noting you want to get the sum of salary, in [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29):

```
SUMMARIZE emp BY { job } ADD ( SUM ( sal ) AS total_sal )
```

Note aggregation is not a relational operator, hence will not form part of a relational algebra.

As for `HAVING`, is it a historical anomaly. Before the SQL-92 Standard, it was not possible to write `SELECT` expressions in the `FROM` clause (a.k.a derived tables) i.e. you had to do all work in one `SELECT` expression. Because of SQL's rigid evaluation order, the aggregate value doesn't come into existence after the `WHERE` clause has been evaluated i.e. it was impossible apply restriction based on aggregated values. `HAVING` was introduced to address this problem.

But even with `HAVING`, SQL remained relationally incomplete as regards Codd's until derived tables had been introduced. Derived tables rendered `HAVING`redundant but using `HAVING` is still popular (if Stackoverflow is anything to go by): folk still seem to like to use a single `SELECT` where possible and SQL's aforementioned rigidity as regards evaluations order (projection is performed last in a `SELECT` expression) makes derived table usage quite verbose when compared to `HAVING`.

Comment: @Martin Smith: I do think that `HAVING` might have aggravated the situation, so I guess it was a Freudian slip :) Now corrected.