# What is the equivalent for a Group By and Having clause query in Relational Algebra?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

Exemple :

7.Find patients who visited two different doctors of the same specialty in the same day.

```
   SELECT       p.pid , d.speciality, v.date
   FROM         Patient p
   JOIN         Visits v ON v.pid = p.pid
   JOIN         Doctors d ON d.did = v.did
   GROUP BY     p.pname, d.speciality, v.date
   HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT d.did) = 2
```

how do you write legit RA for this?

basiclly what is the equivalance of GroupBy and Having Clause in RA?

the same was asked and didnt got answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7728012/equivalent-of-groupby-and-having-clause-in-relational-algebra)

Comment: See the comment of @onedaywhen, under his answer: [Converting aggregate operators from SQL to relational algebra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604969/converting-aggregate-operators-from-sql-to-relational-algebra)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not really need to try and convert SQL, reflecting on the question gives an RA solution as well:

"Find patients who visited two different doctors of the same specialty in the same day"

We start by combining Patients, Visits and Doctors

`Patients x Visits x Doctors`

Since we have two visits and two doctors we need another instance of tables Visits and Doctors. We cannot just use them as they are since otherwise we will not be able to distinguish between them. Hence, renaming `\rho`:

`Patients x \rho_V1(Visits) x \rho_D1(Doctors)  x \rho_V2(Visits) x \rho_D2(Doctors)`

Next we need to select the "matching" combinations

```
\sigma_{Patients.pid = V1.pid /\ 
        Patients.pid = V2.pid /\ 
        V1.date = V2.date /\ 
        V1.did = D1.did /\ 
        V2.did = D2.did /\
        D1.did != D2.did /\
        D1.speciality = D2.speciality}
 (Patients x \rho_V1(Visits) x \rho_D1(Doctors)  x 
             \rho_V2(Visits) x \rho_D2(Doctors))
```

Next we need to find the patients, i.e., project on `pid`

```
\pi_{Patients.pid} 
(\sigma_{Patients.pid = V1.pid /\ 
        Patients.pid = V2.pid /\ 
        V1.date = V2.date /\ 
        V1.did = D1.did /\ 
        V2.did = D2.did /\
        D1.did != D2.did /\
        D1.speciality = D2.speciality}
 (Patients x \rho_V1(Visits) x \rho_D1(Doctors)  x 
             \rho_V2(Visits) x \rho_D2(Doctors)))
```

In this way you have found patients that visited *at least* two different doctors of the same speciality at the same day. If you need to find those patients who visited *exactly* two doctors, you should keep in mind that *exactly 2 = at least 2 - at least 3*, i.e.,

```
\pi_{Patients.pid} 
(\sigma_{Patients.pid = V1.pid /\ 
        Patients.pid = V2.pid /\ 
        V1.date = V2.date /\ 
        V1.did = D1.did /\ 
        V2.did = D2.did /\
        D1.did != D2.did /\
        D1.speciality = D2.speciality}
 (Patients x \rho_V1(Visits) x \rho_D1(Doctors)  x 
             \rho_V2(Visits) x \rho_D2(Doctors)))
-
\pi_{Patients.pid} 
(\sigma_{Patients.pid = V1.pid /\ 
        Patients.pid = V2.pid /\ 
        Paitents.pid = V3.pid /\
        V1.date = V2.date /\ 
        V2.date = V3.date /\
        V1.did = D1.did /\ 
        V2.did = D2.did /\
        V3.did = D3.did /\
        D1.did != D2.did /\
        D1.did != D3.did /\
        D2.did != D3.did /\
        D1.speciality = D2.speciality /\
        D2.speciality = D3.speciality}
 (Patients x \rho_V1(Visits) x \rho_D1(Doctors)  x 
             \rho_V2(Visits) x \rho_D2(Doctors)  x
             \rho_V3(Visits) x \rho_D3(Doctors) ))
```