# Element repeated at least 3 times

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle11g

Is there a way to tell if an element is at least 3 times in a column without using Count and Group By?

> EDIT: The answer is expected in SQL (mysql or oracle11g) in which
>   **only SELECT, FROM, WHERE and JOINS are used**. And of course, all the logical operators and quantifiers as **RELATIONAL CALCULUS WITH
>   TUPLES** has NO tools at all.
>
> Example of tuples:
>
> { t : {name} | ∃ s : {name, wage} ( Employee(s) ∧ s.wage = 50.000 ∧ t.name = s.name ) }
>
> *here, the limitations of Relational Calculus with tuples are clear.*
>
> No CTE's, no group by, no row tools, no distinct, no count, no views, no create, no insert, no alter. None of those awesome SQL tools.

The reason why I don't want to use Count and Group By is because I'll take this to Relational Calculus with Tuples, which doesn't allow those tools.

As an example:

Suppose there is a table ORDER (Id_article, Id_Provider) where both ID's are foreign keys.

Query: Get all the articles that were ordered at least 3 times.

Let the table ORDER be:

```
   Id_Article      Id_Provider

       1               A
       1               B
       1               B
       2               C
       2               C
       3               A
```

The result of the query should be only the element 1, as it is 3 times in Id_Article.

Comment: what is `Relational Calculus`? and why you tag `mysql` and `oracle11`?choose one.

Comment: Because I'm allowed to use any of those two options.

Comment: Relational Calculus is a sw or db? Because probably oracle have other tools you cant use neither :(

Comment: If you had a unique key on the record you could use two EXIST clauses to check for the existence of two other  records with the same Id_Article.

Comment: Yeha, that's what I thought. Unluckily this is the way the model I'm working with was proposed. Just foreign keys with other non unique columns which I ignored for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Down know if this answer your question. But oracle have a `row_number` function

In this case `partition_by` restart the counting with each article.

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b16ffe/26)**

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT    "Id_Article", 
            "Id_Provider", 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY "Id_Article" ORDER BY "Id_Provider")  AS rn
      FROM  Table1
)     
SELECT DISTINCT "Id_Article"
FROM CTE
WHERE rn >= 3;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I wasted your time. I wasn't clear about what Relational Calculus with Tuples is, so I made an EDIT to the question.

Comment: don't worry. But maybe your question is more for `mathematic` overflow instead of programing. They do crazy stuff there.

Comment: I think you are right. I didn't know about this Stackoverflow for Math, so I'll take the question there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

Let's call the following `Ids`

`SELECT O1.id_article AS id
FROM ORDER O1
JOIN ORDER O2 ON O1.id_article = O2.id_article
MINUS
SELECT O3.id_article AS id
FROM ORDER O3
MINUS
SELECT O3.id_article AS id
FROM ORDER O3
MINUS
SELECT O3.id_article AS id
FROM ORDER O3
MINUS
SELECT O3.id_article AS id
FROM ORDER O3`

Then our relational equation is `{ t : {id} | ∃ s : {id} ( Ids(s) ∧ t.id = s.id ) }`

If you can't use `MINUS`, then maybe this can help [Converting aggregate operators from SQL to relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604969/converting-aggregate-operators-from-sql-to-relational-algebra)