# a field from table A IN a field on table B + mysql + php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have two tables with the following structure:

tblA:

```
+----------+---------------+
| id (int) | name (string) |
+----------+---------------+
|        1 | a             |
|        2 | b             |
|        3 | c             |
+----------+---------------+
```

tblB:

```
+----------+---------------+-------------+
| id (int) | name (string) | aid(string) |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
|        1 | x             | '1,2'       |
|        2 | y             | '2,'        |
|        3 | z             | '1,3'       |
+----------+---------------+-------------+
```

```
$a = $this::$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblB WHERE id= :id LIMIT 1');
$a->bindValue(':id', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$a->execute();
$r = $a->fetch(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($a->rowCount() > 0){
    $bInf = $r['id']   . '|*|' .
            $r['name'] . '|*|' .
            $r['aid']  . '|**|';

    $b = $this::$db->prepare('SELECT id,name FROM tblA WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,:ids)');
    $b->bindValue(':ids', $r['aid']);
    $b->execute();
    $rs = $b->fetchAll(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($b->rowCount() > 0)
    {
        foreach ($rs as $srow => $srval)
          $aInf .= $srval['id']   . '[|]' .
                   $srval['name'] . '[#]' ;
    } else
        $aInf = ' ';
        $aInf.=  '|***|' . $bInf; 
    }
}
```

i need to query from tblA and tblB as above sample, but second query dont return any records.

i also tried 'IN' operator but dont worked too...

pls help me...

Comment: Get table B data into a junction table, it will use indexes (think fast), and it will be maintainable

Comment: or should I say it *can* use indexes, and I don't mean left-most only like now in that string

Comment: @Drew ty, It's not possible to use junk table or indexes

Comment: The gentleman over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32556972/1816093) had a well-explained  reason for saying this and that cannot be used. His question had revisions, as proposed solutions came in. I haven't seen any of that sort of explanation here. "Cannot" often means "I don't want to do that".

Comment: @Drew yes you're right, Because the query should only be implemented with 'IN' or 'FIND_IN_SET' or same other operator or func, i'll edit my post with more description soon. ty.

Comment: not that I would answer it. You mean I only want it done with `in` or `find_in_set`, (back to "I don't want to") now don't you :) Good luck either way, hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a funny mistake, by removing ' Character from "aid" field, the problem was solved and FIND_IN_SET works right now.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblb,tbla
WHERE tblb.id= 1 AND FIND_IN_SET(tbla.id, tblb.aid)
```

for details, refer to:

[FIND_IN_SET() vs IN()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155873/find-in-set-vs-in)

Comment: thank you, select from two table in one query is not my solution, but link was useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different approach by extracting each of the ids from `aid` column separately

```
$a = $this::$db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tblB WHERE id= :id LIMIT 1');
$a->bindValue(':id', $ID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$a->execute();
$r = $a->fetch(pdo::FETCH_ASSOC);

if ($a->rowCount() > 0)
{
    $bInf = $r['id']   . '|*|' .
            $r['name'] . '|*|' .
            $r['aid']  . '|**|';

    //extract each of the ids in the variable 'aid'
    $tbla_ids = explode(',',$r['aid']);
    foreach($tbla_ids as $tbla_id){
        //case for the record where aid = '2,'
        if(strlen($tbla_id)==0){
            continue;
        }
        $b = $this::$db->prepare('SELECT id,name FROM tblA WHERE id= :ids');
        $b->bindValue(':ids', $tbla_id);
        $b->execute();
        //do what you need to do here. The query returns the single record
        //from tbla that matches the id $tbla_id
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible, but with low perfomance... i can't use loop's, ty