# relational algebra for this SQL for rows with values that appear more than 3 times

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

What is relational algebra for this SQL for rows with values that appear more than 3 times?

```
select e.id, e.name, e.dno, COUNT(w.id) AS TOTAL_PROJECTS
from employee e,
     works_on w
where e.id = w.id
group by e.id
HAVING TOTAL_PROJECTS > 3;
```

Tables:

```
Employee (id, name, salary, dno)
Department (dno, dname, Mgr_id)
Project(Pno,Pname,dno)
Works_on(id, Pno, No_of_hrs)
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: What is the question? Show us some sample table data, and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Comment: There are many RAs (relational algebras). They differ in operators & even what a relation is. Give definitions & a reference for yours. Eg textbook name, edition & page. Nested RA calls form a programming language. So give as much of a [mre] as you can, even if you are not actually running code. But--Google 'run relational algebra online'. Please show what parts you are able to do. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: [Converting aggregate operators from SQL to relational algebra](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7604969/3404097) Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. PS [Re relational querying.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425914/3404097)

Comment: @MujtabaKably The question was (only) in the title. I edited. But see the other comments.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have an id field in employee or work_on

```
SELECT e.Empid, e.name, e.dno, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL_PROJECTS
FROM employee e JOIN
     works_on w ON e.Empid = w.Empid
GROUP BY e.Empid, e.name, e.dno
HAVING TOTAL_PROJECTS > 3;
```

Comment: They want relational algebra not SQL. Though the column bug would be a relevant comment. Anyway you don't say what the point of this code is if this were an answer.

Comment: i know but try http://dbis-uibk.github.io/relax/calc/local/uibk/local/3 and try it out furst and see ´how far you come

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Did you think I was the asker? I already told them to google online execution & to show what they can do.

Comment: I might have made a mistake in the query i.e. incorrect colum name. My question was to re-write the query but using relational algebra.

Comment: see my comment about creating your sample data and gibe it a try, but with data some one can help you